# Is there a way to calculate the running total across only a few columns (unique values only)?

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the running total across a few specific columns of my dataFrame and I am only interested in calculating using unique values.

I have below an example dataframe:

| Name | Product | Date | Location | Type | Sales | Ship Fee % | Total Fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Bananas | 01-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 |
| Tom | Apples | 01-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 |
| Tom | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | TX | Fruit | 420 | 0.01 | 4.2 |
| Tom | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | TX | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 |
| Mat | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 30 | 0.01 | 0.3 |

I want to have a `Running Total` column, but only considering the Name and Date (as groupBy columns) and showing the sum of the unique values of Total Fee column. That would result in something like this:

| Name | Product | Date | Location | Type | Sales | Ship Fee % | Total Fee | Running Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Bananas | 01-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 | 1.2 |
| Tom | Apples | 01-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 | 1.2 |
| Tom | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | TX | Fruit | 420 | 0.01 | 4.2 | 4.2 |
| Tom | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | TX | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 | 5.4 |
| Mat | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 30 | 0.01 | 0.3 | 0.3 |

I am lost -> I haven't been able to find anything that can give me this result.

Comment: What do you define as unique values?  In other words what is the logic you want to apply in order to def9ine what is and what is not a unique value?

Comment: @itprorh66 by unique values as the unique values of the Total Fee column. In the last example I gave, the 1st row has a Total Fee of 1.2. The second row is the exact same, so I wouldn't consider that value -> remains 1.2.

Comment: @itprorh66 I can't just do remove duplicates because in the actual data set there are other columns where the data is not duplicated. Hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

**Option 1:** `groupby` "Name" and "Date" then `cumsum` only unique values for Total Fee

```
df['Running Total'] = df.drop_duplicates(['Name', 'Date', 'Total Fee']).groupby(['Name', 'Date'])['Total Fee'].cumsum()
df['Running Total'] = df['Running Total'].fillna(df['Total Fee'])
```

**Option 2:** `groupby` "Name", "Product", "Date". Then `cumsum` --> gives the accumulated sum for each product on each day for each person.

```
df['Running Total'] = df.groupby(['Name', 'Product','Date'], as_index=False)['Total Fee'].cumsum()
```

---

**Testing and examples**

Given this dataframe:

|  | Name | Product | Date | Location | Type | Sales | Ship Fee % | Total Fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Tom | Bananas | 01-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 |
| 1 | Tom | Apples | 01-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 |
| 2 | Tom | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | TX | Fruit | 420 | 0.01 | 4.2 |
| 3 | Tom | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | TX | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 |
| 4 | Mat | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 30 | 0.01 | 0.3 |
| 5 | Mat | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 50 | 0.01 | 0.3 |
| 6 | Mat | Apples | 03-01-2021 | NY | Vegetable | 80 | 0.02 | 1.6 |

**Option 1 result:**

|  | Name | Product | Date | Location | Type | Sales | Ship Fee % | Total Fee | Running Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Tom | Bananas | 01-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 | 1.2 |
| 1 | Tom | Apples | 01-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 | 1.2 |
| 2 | Tom | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | TX | Fruit | 420 | 0.01 | 4.2 | 4.2 |
| 3 | Tom | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | TX | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 | 5.4 |
| 4 | Mat | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 30 | 0.01 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| 5 | Mat | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 50 | 0.01 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| 6 | Mat | Apples | 03-01-2021 | NY | Vegetable | 80 | 0.02 | 1.6 | 1.6 |

**Option 2 result:**

|  | Name | Product | Date | Location | Type | Sales | Ship Fee % | Total Fee | Running Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Tom | Bananas | 01-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 | 1.2 |
| 1 | Tom | Apples | 01-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 | 1.2 |
| 2 | Tom | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | TX | Fruit | 420 | 0.01 | 4.2 | 4.2 |
| 3 | Tom | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | TX | Fruit | 120 | 0.01 | 1.2 | 5.4 |
| 4 | Mat | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 30 | 0.01 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| 5 | Mat | Bananas | 02-01-2021 | NY | Fruit | 50 | 0.01 | 0.3 | 0.6 |
| 6 | Mat | Apples | 03-01-2021 | NY | Vegetable | 80 | 0.02 | 1.6 | 1.6 |

Comment: Hi Pedro, I am getting the below error:
```ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 5 elements```

Comment: I've updated the code. The error was for rows with the same value in Name,Product,Date and Total Fee. I was using x.unique() and it wasn't needed. Now I think that it's working ok.

Comment: But in this case it will not ```cumsum``` the unique values only, right? :)

Comment: I've updated the answer. I think option 1 will solve your problem. Sorry about the miss understanding

Comment: I've fix the filling of missing values on option 1, but if you wanted to leave the Running Total as NaN for unique values just delete the second line of code